# Tesseract - Entire line output

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am trying to OCR few tables using Tesseract. These tables have following format:

```
Item One name                       Item One category
(Item description if any)

Item Two name                       Item Two category
(Item description if any)
```

There is some space between the name and category. The output produced is like this

```
Item One name
(Item description if any)

Item Two name
(Item description if any)


Item One category

Item Two category
```

Is there a way that I can produce output for the entire line and not get this column wise output one below the other?

I am running Tesseract through simple command line:

```
tesseract ~/Desktop/imagename.jpg out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a different page segmentation mode (PSM), such as 4 or 6.