# pytessarect / Tessarect rowwise line output

Tags: python-3.x, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am using pytessarect (0.2.5) for reading documents in varying structure on the same page, namely:

```
SomeText
SomeText
SomeText

SomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeTextSomeText

SomeText:  SomeText  SomeText: SomeText:
SomeText:  SomeText  SomeText SomeText SomeText
SomeText:  SomeText
SomeText:  SomeText

SomeText:  SomeText
SomeText:  SomeText
```

I want tessarect to read in the data linewise and so far i just found the psm option (varying between 0-13, most recommended using psm 4 or 6) through posts with similar issues ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687127/tesseract-entire-line-output) and [Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/0vIBS-KP-Ss)). Unfortunately, i tried every option for psm and could resolve my issue. I looked in the documentation, but couldn't find another option. Has someone encountered a similar issue and resolved it successfully? Is there a way to force tesseract to read the image linewise despite psm?
Any help much appreciated!

Edit:Right now the lower part is read in columnwise, which i try to prevent.

Edit2: Commands added

```
text = [] 
tess_cfg = '--psm 6 --oem 1 --hocr'   
for image in images:
   text= pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(image), lang = 'eng', config = tess_cfg)
```

Comment: Can you please upload the image you are using ? and the command you are running ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the image are contract, so i cannot upload those, I hope my Code helps a little bit.

Comment: What you need is `pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr` and not `image_to_string`

Answer (score 0):

I could find my bug, it seems there is a difference whether you use `tess_cfg = '--psm 6 --oem 1 --hocr'`  or `tess_cfg = '-psm 6 -oem 1 -hocr'`. The first one didn't seem to work properly.